# Flutter Xcode build failed due to missing dependencies even when those have been deleted from pubspec.yalm

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I add a dependency to the `pubspec.yaml` file no matter if the IDE runs the pub get command or if I run it manually, it seems like the packages are being imported correctly (or that is what I think), however, if I "change my mind" and delete the package from the `pubspec.yaml` file, and again pub get, I am unable to build the app anymore, seems like the packages are still linked somehow to the app, even when there is no code related to them, the only way I can get back to work is by cleaning up all... e.g.

```
cd ios
cd ..
pod deintegrate
flutter clean
flutter pub cache repair
flutter pub get
cd ios
Pod install
Pod repo update
```

Maybe I am missing a step when working with dependencies.